# EntityModel with Ideablade giving problems on server

Tags: c#, silverlight, edmx, devforce

**Problem**

When I test my project on live environment, it works perfect. All connections are properly made and both edmx will work properly.

However, when I publish it to our webserver, one of the edmx files will return a "The remote server returned error: Not Found"
(see picture)
[image: Error]

**Information**

We are using a silverlight 5 project with IdeaBlade v6.1.7.0, Caliburn.Micro v1.3.1.0 and MefContrib.Silverlight v1.1.0.0

We have put a seperate Class Library with our edmx files in there.

We have 2 edmx files. One for normal data and one for localization.

Currently I have found out that the EDMX for StaticContent does not work! it will always return the error shown in the image above.

But when I test it on my local machine things work perfectly.

I am looking for anyone that can help me in anyway, if more information is needed; feel free to ask.

**List of things I've already tried**

I've tried to re-add the staticcontent edmx.

I've tried to combine them but this resulted in a lot more errors and difficulties.

I've tried to set the staticcontent edmx datasource key to the same as the other edmx

All custom dll's are set to "Copy Local = true"

Answer (score 1):

You'll get the NotFound error on a client when it can't communicate with the EntityServer.  This generally doesn't have anything to do with the EDMX itself, unless you're using data source extensions with each model.

Unfortunately, there are many reasons why a client won't be able to communicate with the server.  You can first check if the service is running by navigating to its service page, as described [here](http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/deploy-troubleshooting-ntier#HHowtoseeiftheEntityServerisrunning).  If there's a problem with the service you'll see errors shown on this page.

Also see [this page](http://drc.ideablade.com/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/deploy-iis) for information on deployment steps, to see if you've got everything needed.